# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING'

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

i got an error while running this code

```
    if not faceFound:
        if lastface == 0 or lastface == 1:
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   # there seems to be an issue in OpenCV or V4L or my webcam-
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   #   driver, I'm not sure which, but if you wait too long,
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   #   the webcam consistantly gets exactly five frames behind-
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   #   realtime. So we just grab a frame five times to ensure-
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   
            fface = frontalface.detectMultiScale(aframe,1.3,4,(cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING + cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT + cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH),(60,60))
            if fface != ():         
                lastface = 1        
                for f in fface:     
                    faceFound = True
                    face = f
```

i got this error

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING'

i tried to install 'pip install opencv-python'

Answer (score 0):

Change  this:

```
fface = frontalface.detectMultiScale(aframe,1.3,4,(cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING + cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT + cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH),(60,60))
```

to:

```
fface = frontalface.detectMultiScale(aframe,1.3,4,(cv2.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING + cv2.CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT + cv2.CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH),(60,60))
```